# Optimizing a request doing tons of exclusions

Tags: sql

I have a huge and dirty SQL request doing many exclusions and I feel bad about it. Perhaps, you know a better way to proceed.

Here's a part of my request:

```
select name, version, iteration, score
    from article, articlemaster
    where article.idmaster = articlemaster.id
            and article.id not in (select article.id
                                from article, spsarticlemaster
                                where article.idmaster = articlemaster.id
                                and articlemaster.name = 'nameOfMyArticle'
                                and article.version = 'A'
                                and article.state = 'CONTINUE')
            and article.id not in....
            and article.id not in....
```

You think it doesn't look that bad ? Actually, this is only a portion of the request, the "and spsarticle.id not in ...." exclude one article, and i got more than 1000 to exclude, so i'm using a java program to append the other 999.

Any idea how could i make a light version of this abomination ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off loading all of the articles to exclude into a temporary table, then joining that table in to your query.

For example, create `exclude_articles`:

```
name            version   state
----            -------   -----
nameOfMyArticle A         CONTINUE
```

Then exclude its results from the query:

```
select
    article.name,
    article.version,
    article.iteration,
    article.score
from
    article
    join articlemaster
         on article.idmaster = articlemaster.id
where
    not exists (
        select 1
          from article article2
               join articlemaster articlemaster2
                    on article2.idmaster = articlemaster2.id
               join exclude_articles
                    on articlemaster2.name = exclude_articles.name
                    and article2.version = exclude_articles.version
                    and article2.state = exclude_articles.state
         where article.id = article2.id)
```

This is all assuming that the `version` and `state` are actually necessary for the exclusion logic.  It would be a much easier case if the name is unique.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Java to create the query and process the results, then why not do all the complicated logic in Java?  Just ask the database for all the articles matching some basic criterion (or maybe you really do want to read through all of them) and then filter the results:

```
select am.name, a.version, a.iteration, a.score, a.state
from   article a, articlemaster am
where  a.idmaster = am.id
  and  <some other basic criteria>
```

Then in Java loop over all the results (sorry, my Java is super rusty) and filter out the ones you don't want:

```
ArrayList recordList = ArrayList();
ArrayList finalList = ArrayList();
for (record in recordList) {
    if (! filterThisRecord(record)) {
        finalList.append(record);
    }
}
```